# Set the Dynamic Width to TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to set the dynamic width to `Html.TextBoxFor` according to value get from Model

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Agenda, new { @readonly = "readonly", id = "abc",@style="width:auto" })
```

but this is not working. I want to change every time the width according to "Agenda " value from model.

Comment: Are you trying to set the width of the textbox or the html page? Are you setting the width based on the value or data or the length of it?

Comment: Trying to set the width of the textbox based on the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to set the width of the text box as a user types, you can use jQuery to accomplish this. However you have not been very clear on what determines the length of the textbox so if you want to the textbox to increase in size as they user types you could use something like this:

```
$('#abc').on('keyup', (function() {
  var size = $(this).val().length();

  $(this).css( 'width', size + 'px' );
});
```